# Python: how to check a condition in a nested loop?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have a program like this one:

```
one_tuple = ((0, 1, 2),
             (3, 4, 5),
             (6, 7, 8),
             (0, 3, 6),
             (1, 4, 7),
             (2, 5, 8),
             (0, 4, 8),
             (2, 4, 6))
def function():
    for tuples in one_tuple:
        for variables in tuple:
           see if ceratin conditions are true....
```

*this is  an artificial intelligence for a program called "Tic tac toe" and this part checks every winning combination, nested for loops seemed like the easiest solution for that (that's why sub tuples have 3 elements) and I need to go through each element and check them (for example if a sub tuple has 2 noughts or 2 crosses and 1 empty field then it needs to append that field to a list, in my example the program will never know if someone can win by taking that empty field)*

Comment: Can you show example output? I don't get what exactly do you want.

Comment: Well this is an artificial intelligence for a program called "Tic tac toe" and this part checks every winning combination, nested for loops seemed like the easiest solution for that (that's why sub tuples have 3 elements) and I need to go through each element and check them (for example if a sub tuple has 2 noughts or 2 crosses and 1 empty field then it needs to append that field to a list, in my example the program will never know if someone can win by taking that empty field).

Comment: which field to a list? Are you trying to find 3 connected x's or o's?

Comment: Yes, the program needs to know if it needs to block that empty field or take it before the player to win (or to stop the player from winning, or in short like you said, find 3 connected x's or o's).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` for each sub-tuple to check your condition for each element of that tuple. For example, say you want to check if all the elements of the tuple are greater than `2`

```
def foo(tup):
    for sub in tup:
        if all(i > 2 for i in sub):
            print("all greater than two")

>>> foo(one_tuple)
all greater than two
all greater than two
```

Comment: Ok but all elements will be different and this won't work (the last if statement needs to check 3 values and if they are true then it needs to do something, this statement will only be executed after the 2nd loop finishes (but of course it will simply jump back to the 1st loop without executing that condition)).

Comment: @user3711671 You'll have to show a concrete example of what you are talking about, with actual numbers and expected output. It's kind of hard to understand your question just using words.

Comment: Explained under my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use  a dict for the board and store winning combinations. if two out of three positions are filled we know the remaining position is a winning one. This is a quick example of the logic where `one_tuple` is replaced by winning combs:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# 8 potential winning combs for 9 item board
winning_combs = [(0, 1, 2), (0, 3, 6), (0, 4, 8), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8), (1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (2, 4, 6)]
# set all to False for an empty board
board = OrderedDict((k, False) for k in range(10))
board[0] = True # simulate two moves 0 and 1 are set 
board[1] =  True
# anywhere we find two positions taken in a potential winning combo we will return the key/position
opps = [k for tup in winning_combs if sum(board[t] for t in tup) == 2 for k in tup if not board[k]]
print(opps) # returns 2 the potential winning position
```